# Does my residuals vs fitted values plot show constant variance for my regression?

Tags: regression, heteroscedasticity

I'm having trouble interpreting my R output. I know when checking for variance no patterns should occur but I have only covered the textbook scenario where it is very easy to interpret. However with my output I was just wondering does the validated of constant variance hold up?[image]

Comment: I've tried giving a clearer title - I suspect that you mean "assumption" instead of "validated" in the final line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is difficult to judge a plot with such few data points. You could try a formal test of heteroscedasticity such as the [Breusch-Pagan test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breusch%E2%80%93Pagan_test), implemented in the `ncvTest` function of the `car` package. Given how small your data set is, I would be surprised if significant heteroscedasticity is found.

The size of your data set is a more fundamental issue. A good rule of thumb is you should have 10-20 observations per parameter in your model, so your data set is borderline too small to fit a linear model with even one predictor.

Comment: Hi Slow, thank you for your comment but I have not  the Breech-Pagan test therefore it is not required. I have only started linear regression and just want to make some comment on the graph that I got. The other assumptions hold i.e that the residuals are normally distributed and they are independent. But I was hoping to pass some remark on this.

Comment: I think you would be safe saying that it is difficult to tell based on such few data points, but there is perhaps a slight suggestion of non-linearity (U-shaped pattern). Something like this could happen if your response variable grows exponentially but you try to model it with a linear model, e.g., `plot(lm(1.3^(1:8)~c(1:8)), which=1)`